# Actionbarのmenu itemをクリックした時の動作

Tags: android, android-fragments

はじめまして。皆様どうかお知恵を御貸しください。

Android の ActionBar の menuItem をクリックした時の動作についてです。 
よく、 Toast などの処理はみるのですが、画面遷移（Actionbar の menu から ListFragment へ）などが見つかりません。 
`onOptionsItemSelected` 内で 
どのように、画面遷移を指定すべきか、教えて頂けますと幸いです。 
現在は以下のように試しております。しかし、 `menu_home` を押すと落ちてしまう状況です。 
どのように書き直すべきでしょうか？ 
遷移先は、 `ListFragment` です。

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_home:
            Fragment mEvent = new Event();
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.menu_home, mEvent).commit();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
replace(R.id.menu_home, mEvent)
```

とあるので、メニューボタンをmEventフラグメントで`replace`しようとしているのが原因です

Comment: ありがとうございます。仰る通りで、メニューボタンにfragmentをreplaceしようとしているのが原因でした。

Answer (score 1):

それぞれの機能を見ていくと

`beginTransaction()`フラグメントの変更を開始します

`commit()`フラグメントの変更を確定します。

`replace(A,B)`Aで指定されたViewのidにBで指定されたフラグメントを表示します。
もともとそこにフラグメントがあれば削除します。

`R.id.menu_home`各オプションメニューに割り当てられたidです

`show()`Viewに割り当てられたフラグメントを表示します。

落ちるときにログに以下は載っていませんか

> No view found for id ～～

メッセージの通り`R.id.menu_home`はViewのidではありません。
replace(A,B)に渡すのは表示させたいViewのidです。

Comment: 御丁寧に回答頂きましてありがとうございます。
仰るように、menuItemにFragmentをreplaceしようとしているのが問題でした。
menu_homeをcontainerに置き換える事で対応できました。(ついでにFragmentManagerもgetActivityを加えています。)
皆様ありがとうございました。

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();

switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_home:
            Fragment mEvent = new Event();
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, mEvent).commit();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}